# Entity Framework ambiguity problems when refreshing model from database

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to update my model from the database, which has a new column on one of the tables.

I use the Update Model From Database wizard, and it seems to work alright, until I try to compile.

Then I get tons of ambiguous call errors, as if the code had been duplicated elsewhere, but the model looks fine.

I'm using VS2012 Update 2 and EF4. What's going on?

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: ambiguous method invocations, as if the same methods were defined twice :(

Comment: What exactly have you done while updating? Did you by any chance change anything in the code generation strategy?